# selenium find_elements being extremly slow when there isnt element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
images_container = driver_new.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="prod_add"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]')
images = images_container.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'p')

for p_index, p_element in enumerate(images):

    img_elements = p_element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'img')


    
    for img_index, img_element in enumerate(img_elements):
        try:
            
            image = img_element.get_attribute('src')

            
            image_extension = os.path.splitext(image)[1]

            
            save_path = f"images/content_{p_index}_{img_index}{image_extension}"
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(image, save_path)
            
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
```

im trying to get images on a website. above code works and saves image files but the problem is when p.element doesn't have the tag 'img' its extremly slow to move on.
is there something im missing?

Comment: The slowness you're experiencing in your code is likely due to the fact that when p_element doesn't have the 'img' tag, your code still goes through the entire try-catch block for each p_element. This adds unnecessary overhead and makes the code slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why do you use try / catch implementation, when you can filter images with src, using correct locator.

Css locator `img[src]` filters images, where src attribute is assigned.

There shouldn't be big difference in time for exextion between `find_elements` by tag and by css locator.

So if the issue in `get_attribute`, it should work faster now.

```
img_elements = p_element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'img[src]')
```

Answer (score 0):

only get into checking p_element when image exist in that

```
images_container = driver_new.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="prod_add"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]')
    images = images_container.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'p')
    
    for p_index, p_element in enumerate(images):
        img_elements = p_element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'img')
        
        # Check if img_elements is not empty before processing
        if img_elements:
            for img_index, img_element in enumerate(img_elements):
                try:
                    image = img_element.get_attribute('src')
                    image_extension = os.path.splitext(image)[1]
                    save_path = f"images/content_{p_index}_{img_index}{image_extension}"
                    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image, save_path)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(str(e))
```

Comment: thats what i first thought but its actually img_elements = p_element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'img') this part. when there isn't tag name 'img', for some reason its taking so long to move on. so even if i put if img_elements like you provided, it wouldnt do anything since img_elements = p_element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'img') is the slow part